# NULL pointer error in production only on first start

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I currently have an issue when I deploy my Titanium alloy application to the play store, when I launch it for the first time it crashes. This only happens in production.

When I reported the issue the following is what I found in the developer console:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
>   on a null object reference    at
>   android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:359)    at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:3663)  at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:3758)  at
>   android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:650)     at
>   android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:645)     at
>   android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:641)     at
>   android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:637)     at
>   ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUILabel$1.(TiUILabel.java:58)
>     at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUILabel.(TiUILabel.java:57)
>     at ti.modules.titanium.ui.LabelProxy.createView(LabelProxy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:490)
>     at
>   org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:476)
>     at
>   org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleToImage(TiViewProxy.java:965)
>     at
>   org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleMessage(TiViewProxy.java:280)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)

Since I don't know where excalty it went wrong since it is in production I don't know what code to supply. I understand it is a null reference error, but nowhere in my application I use a getResources() function, or something like that.

The second time I run it it just works

Titanium Version: 6.0.1.GA

Mac OS X: 10.12.3

Target android SDK: 23

Android version: 5.1

Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It is not a duplicate

Comment: Resources is used for styling or images. Your error seems to indicate a `<TextView>` or View property. Are you trying to override a specific property, or depending on a TextView to exist? Are you storing anything to memory and using that later (properties for example)